# strange behavior with socket.recv

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, file-sharing

**CODE**

```
import socket
import os
import compression
import time

SUCCESS_FILE_SENT = "101"
SUCCESS_FILE_RECIEVED = "201"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

def receive_file(conn, fileInfo):
    try:
        fileInfo[1] = int(fileInfo[1])
        with open(fileInfo[0], "wb") as f:
            bytes_sent = 0
            while True: 
                data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if (data == b"end") or (not data):
                    break
                elif data:
                    f.write(data)
                    bytes_sent += len(data)
                    progress = bytes_sent / fileInfo[1] * 100
                    print(f"Recieved {bytes_sent}/{fileInfo[1]} bytes ({progress:.2f}%)")
            return SUCCESS_FILE_RECIEVED
    except Exception as e:
        return f"ERROR: {e}"
            
def send_file(conn, fileInfo):
    try:
        fileInfo[1] = int(fileInfo[1])
        with open(fileInfo[0], "rb") as f:
            bytes_sent = 0
            while True:
                data = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                if not data:
                    break
                conn.send(data)
                bytes_sent += len(data)
                progress = bytes_sent / fileInfo[1] * 100
                print(f"Sent {bytes_sent}/{fileInfo[1]} bytes ({progress:.2f}%)")
            conn.send(b"end")
            return SUCCESS_FILE_SENT
    except Exception as e:
        return f"ERROR: {e}"
def start_server():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        SERVER_PORT = 9999
        
        # Binding the host and port
        s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

        # Listening on the server
        s.listen()
        print(f"Server listening on {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")

        # accepting connections from clients
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection established from {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}")

        # Receive file from client
        fileinfo = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode().split(",")
        print(f"Receiving file {fileinfo[0]} from client...")
        res = receive_file(conn, fileinfo)
        if res == "201":
            print(f"{fileinfo[0]} received.")
        else:
            print(res)

        # compress files into a single file
        fileinfo = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]
        fileinfo = compression.create_archive(fileinfo)

        # Send the compressed archive to client
        fileinfo = [fileinfo, str(os.path.getsize(fileinfo))]
        conn.send(",".join(fileinfo).encode())
        # time.sleep(0.01)
        print(f"Sending file {fileinfo[0]} to server...")
        res = send_file(conn, fileinfo)
        if res == "101":
            print(f"{fileinfo[0]} sent.")
        else:
            print(res)
        os.remove(fileinfo[0])
        # close connection with client
        conn.close()
        print("Connection closed")
        
def start_client():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT = input("Enter the address of server: ").split(":")
        s.connect((SERVER_HOST,int(SERVER_PORT)))
        print(f"Connected to server {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")

        # Send file to server
        fileinfo = ["sample.txt"]
        fileinfo += [str(os.path.getsize(fileinfo[0]))]
        s.send(",".join(fileinfo).encode())
        print(f"Sending file {fileinfo[0]} to server...")
        res = send_file(s, fileinfo)
        if res == "101":
            print(f"{fileinfo[0]} sent.")
        else:
            print(res)

        # Receive compressed archive from server
        fileinfo = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode().split(",")
        print(f"Receiving file {fileinfo[0]} from client...")
        res = receive_file(s, fileinfo)
        if res == "201":
            print(f"{fileinfo[0]} received.")
        else:
            print(res)

        # decompress received archive
        compression.extract_archive(fileinfo[0])
        os.remove(fileinfo[0])
        
        # close connection with server
        s.close()
        print("Connection closed")
```

**ISSUE**
I created a simple application based on client-server model.
Before every file is being send or recieved client/server send filename and filesize to server/client.

First the server receive the file details
`fileinfo = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode().split(",")`
then the file `res = receive_file(conn, fileinfo)`

When same thing done with the client, when client receive details
`fileinfo = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode().split(",")`
and file `res = receive_file(s, fileinfo)`
it gives an error as shown in the output which clearly shows that the data recieved is not only the details but it also include the file data.

**FIX & QUESTION**
When I add line `time.sleep(0.01)` to delay between sending details and file it works great.
Now my **question** here is why the same code is behaving differently??? In the first code, my code worked without delay, but in the second time, I had to add a delay.

**output for server**

```
Server listening on 172.28.144.1:9999...
Connection established from 172.28.144.1:51352
Receiving file sample.txt from client...
Recieved 26/26 bytes (100.00%)
sample.txt received.
Sending file eyFxoKXZRLLdhHI.lz4 to server...
Sent 2727/2727 bytes (100.00%)
eyFxoKXZRLLdhHI.lz4 sent.
Connection closed
```

**output for client**

```
Enter the address of server: 172.28.144.1:9999
Connected to server 172.28.144.1:9999
Sending file sample.txt to server... 
Sent 26/26 bytes (100.00%)
sample.txt sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Code Playground\Python\fileSharing\fileSharing (2).py", line 158, in <module>
    start_client()
  File "d:\Code Playground\Python\fileSharing\fileSharing (2).py", line 138, in start_client
    fileinfo = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode().split(",")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 38: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, not at a remote site.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. You can't assume that every `send()` will correspond to a single `recv()`. Buffers can be merged or split, and `conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` will not wait until `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes have been received (unless you use `flags=socket.MSG_WAITALL`).

Comment: i learned that the default behaviour for `socket.recv` is blocks indefinitely. which means it waits and waits until it receive data. when the first `recv()` recieves data it takes the data and exit. but why wait for another `send()` to receive data

Comment: It blocks until there's something to read, then it returns whatever it has, even if it's not as much as you were expecting. `MSG_WAITALL` makes it wait until it gets `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes or the connection closes.

Comment: i see. but i don't think so `MSG_WAITALL` could resolve my issue. as you said by using using this flag it waits until all of the bytes in their passed-in array have been filled in. just for the sake of example the file details becomes 128 bytes of size and the `BUFFER_SIZE` is 4096 bytes. now this results in the same issue which i am facing. it also recieve the data of file to fill the `BUFFER_SIZE` byte array.
correct me if i am wrong... do i work with delay to solve it??

Comment: Don't use `BUFFER_SIZE`. If you're expecting a message of 100 characters and you want to read the whole message, use `conn.recv(100, flags=MSG_WAITALL)`

Comment: If it's not fixed-size messages, you could first send the message size (e.g. as 4 bytes), followed by the message. The receiver uses `size = conn.recv(4, MSG_WAITALL)` first, then `msg = conn.recv(int(size), flag=MSG_WAITALL)`